# Checking if value is in a list without using "in"

Tags: python, string, list

I want to write a function that checks whether a 'value' is within a list. I have come up with a way to do it using "in" but now I want to find a way that works without using it.

My code with it looks like this:

```
def is_member(value, l):
    if value in l:
        print("is member")
        return True
    else: 
        print("not member")
        return False
```

and it works with all these asserts

```
assert is_member(2, [1, 2, 3])
assert not is_member(0, [1, 2, 3])
assert is_member('C', 'CATG')
assert not is_member('U', 'CATG')
```

In what way can I achieve the same thing (in a simple, beginner way) without using "in"?

Comment: What is the reason?

Comment: @JanStránský practice

Comment: practice of what? What is the reason to practice this? I am just curious

Answer (score 0):

Use `count`

Which gives how many times an item occurs in a list

If the count > 0 that means that specific item was in the list!

Code:

```
def is_member(value, l):
    if l.count(value)>0:
        print("is member")
        return True
    else: 
        print("not member")
        return False
assert is_member(2, [1, 2, 3])
assert not is_member(0, [1, 2, 3])
assert is_member('C', 'CATG')
assert not is_member('U', 'CATG')
```

Comment: I would think that this is an exercise in doing something with as primitive a method as possible for the sake of understanding lower level programming patterns. Substituting `in` with `count` hardly fulfils that goal, it's just more obscure.

Comment: @Kuldeep yes that worked! Can you shortly explain what count does?

Comment: @deceze you assume correctly. Is there an even simpler way then?

Comment: @SanchoPanza I have added explanation!

Comment: @KuldeepSinghSidhu Thank you! Is there an ever more basic way to do it? It looks like deceze means to say there is.

Comment: @SanchoPanza This is the best that comes to my mind. Will update if I find something better in future.

Answer (score 0):

The more primitive pattern, and what `in` indirectly does under the hood in some form or another, would be:

```
def is_member(value, l):
    for i in l:
        if value == i:
            print("is member")
            return True

    print("not member")
    return False
```

You loop through all values, compare them with the searched-for value, and if you find a match, you `return True` and end your function. Should the function run off the end of the list without finding a match, it'll `return False`.

Even more primitively:

```
it = iter(l)
while True:
    try:
        i = next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        print('not member')
        return False

    if i == value:
        print('is member')
        return True
```

This is basically unrolled what the `for .. in` loop does: it creates an *iterator* and gets its `next` value until it raises a `StopIteration`.

Comment: This still uses in though.

Comment: But not *that* `in`. This is a [`for .. in`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement), not a [`value in l`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in). You'd have to bend backwards *really* far to iterate that list entirely avoiding the keyword "`in`".

Comment: @SanchoPanza no, it doesn't.

Comment: @SanchoPanza There is also an `in` in `print`. I don't know if that is a problem.

Comment: I guess `return any(map(lambda i: i == value, l))` would do to avoid `in`, but that's hardly a more primitive pattern for the sake of practice.

Comment: @deceze Or a `while` loop in place of a `for` loop. But you're right, you're not using *that* in. Anyway, in all honesty I don't care much for these problems of "do X without using Y", regardless of whether they are set for personal practice or a class exercise.

Comment: @alani I can see the use in implementing what *that* `in` does manually for the sake of understanding algorithmic complexity. But any other "do this just not in this way" is simply unproductive.

Comment: @deceze Well at least I guess it helps in understanding why the other answer involving `count` is a bad one in the event of an early match...

Comment: @deceze Do you have the energy to show me how it could look with a while loop?

Comment: @SanchoPanza In the case where `l` is something that can be indexed and not just iterated over (e.g. a list), you could have an index variable and increment it inside a `while` loop (stop when it equals the length). It will not be equivalent to all uses of `in`, but you are only using it with strings and lists.

Comment: @Sancho Added *one* kind of `while` example.

Comment: @deceze In terms of showing how it corresponds to the `for` loop, would it be better to `break` in the `except` block and do the rest after the loop?

Comment: @alani There are many ways to skin this cat, which is where we get into the unproductive area…